# Guice ThrowingProvider of interface

Tags: guice, provider, throw

I haven't got much experience with guice extensions. I would appreciate some guidance.
Could someone give me an example of how to implement a throwing provider for an interface and not a concrete class.

For instance a javax.mail.Session. How can I convert the code to a throwing provider?

```java
public class MailSessionProvider implements Provider<Session> {

  @Inject
  @Named("mailSession")
  private static String snName;

  @Override
  public Session get() {
     Session session = null;
     try {
        Context ctx = new InitialContext();
        return (Session) ctx.lookup(snName);
     } catch (NamingException e) {

     }
     return session;
  }
```

}

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the documentation?: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ThrowingProviders

Comment: yes I did and they look pretty obvious except the binding part. I tried to bind my implementation  and it looks like I can only  bind a concrete class not an interface like Session or jdbc.Connection. So there must be something I get wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since Guice-3.0, you have to use the CheckedProvider like this:

```
public class MailSessionThrowingProvider implements CheckedProvider<Session> {

@Inject
@Named("mailSession")
private static String snName;

@Override
public Session get() throws NamingException {
    final Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    return (Session) ctx.lookup(snName);
}
}
```